# How can I select the folder of my upload?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to upload on my folder some files using this form:

```html
      <form>
         <input type="file" name="name" multiple><br><br>
         After uploading multiple files, click Submit.<br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
```

I'm using a view where I display all the files in my folder using FileAdmin module. This module currently a function to upload files but only 1 by 1 that's why I'm trying to create this form.

Somehow, the function of FileAdmin actually works as:

```html
        {% if admin_view.can_upload %}
        <div class="btn-group">
            {%- if admin_view.upload_modal -%}
              {{ lib.add_modal_button(url=get_dir_url('.download', path=dir_path, modal=True),
                                      btn_class="btn btn-default btn-large",
                                      content=_gettext('Upload File')) }}
            {% else %}
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-large" href="{{ get_dir_url('.upload', path=dir_path) }}">{{ _gettext('Upload File ') }}</a> 
            {%- endif -%}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

At the moment, I can select multiple files, click on Submit button but nothing happens.

My question is how can I specify the folder where I'll upload the files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I remember you can check path of the file uploaded, it was like "/var/tmp/" and then move to other path. Take care with permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few attributes from your form. It should be something like this:

`<form action='/your_view_handling_the_request' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>`

and then handle that request in your view

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['name']
    f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_file_uploading

Comment: I didn't get a point. What should be the view handling the request and how can I call it using Flask? I saw some topics which says that Flask and PHP were not in accordance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specified the path as below.

```
form action="your-url-to-file-submission-page"`
```

Comment: What should be the file submission page? I've tried to redirect into the submission page of the module, but they are not linked.

Comment: you have to create a view page on views.py of the app for the submission page and link that view to a URLs as a post method request.

Comment: yes, I finally found a way to pass through my issue!